# Adding Multiple Enums to JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, enums, jcombobox

I want to add different Enums to a single JComboBox. Here is how the code looks like. Type contains 3 different type of Enums(Colors, Shapes, Dimensions).

```
final JComboBox typeJComboBox = new JComboBox(Type.Colors.values());
for(Type.Shapes shape: Type.Shapes.values()) {
typeJComboBox .addItem(shape);
}
for(Type.Dimensions dimension : Type.Dimensions.values()) {
typeJComboBox .addItem(dimension );
}
```

What generic type do I use? When using eclipse, there is a yellow squiggly line under JComboBox and when you hover your mouse over it, it says "Infer Generic Type Arguments...".

Comment: [crossposted](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/461224/adding-multiple-enums-to-jcombobox)

Comment: Crossposted? What's that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as follows:

```
public static <E extends Enum<?>> void main(String[] args)
{
    final JComboBox<E> typeJComboBox = new JComboBox(Type.Colors.values());
    for(Type.Shapes shape : Type.Shapes.values())
    {
        typeJComboBox.addItem((E) shape);
    }
    for(Type.Dimensions dimension : Type.Dimensions.values())
    {
        typeJComboBox.addItem((E) dimension);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like I am not able to cast shape or dimension as E. I used it outside main.